# Hugo site doesn't display properly when deployed to github pages

Tags: github-pages, hugo

When uploading a Hugo site to Github pages, the site looks like it's partially loaded with many of its content missing. What can be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

One primary cause would be that the `baseURL` in your `config` file might be set wrong.

Set it to `baseURL = "https://<your-username>.github.io/` if it is a user/organization page or `baseURL = "https://<your-username>.github.io/<your-project-name>` if it is a project page.

You can usually find the `config` file in the root of your Hugo project with the name `config.toml`